# How to get session from webview.?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a question, the problem is that, I have some webview

```
<WebView
      ref={(r) => (this.webref = r)}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
      source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
      scalesPageToFit={false}
      onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
      onMessage={(event) => {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.data);
      }}
    />
```

I also have a code that works after loading webview

```
onLoadEnd = () => {
  this.webref.injectJavaScript(
    `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(window.localStorage.getItem('session'))`,
  );
};
```

can I somehow get the session after user authorization / registration? If I can, how? Because my injectjavascript () fires once after loading the webview

Comment: Perhaps I did not quite correctly put it, but the session is generated after the user is registered / atorized and now I need to catch this very moment and then hook it

Comment: Do you need to access, sessionStorage from web-view?

Comment: I can get data from the local storage, but my injected script shoots only 1 time and shoots immediately after loading the web view, but I need it to fire after registration or authorization and I get a session ID